# Powershell/C#: Import and Invoke Nested Modules

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

This is how I load the nested modules in a ListBox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        readonly PowerShell _ps = PowerShell.Create();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _ps.AddScript("Import-Module MyModules");
            _ps.AddScript("(Get-Module MyModules).NestedModules");
            Collection<PSObject> psObjects = _ps.Invoke();

            foreach (var psObject in psObjects)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(psObject);
            }
}
```

Now, if the user has selected a specific Module, I want to execute the same.

This does not seem to work [although module should be loaded and it should recognize the command] -

```
_ps.AddCommand(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()).Invoke();
```

**Exception:**

> The term 'MyModule1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

I assume that the Module would have been loaded in the memory by now and I have to just Invoke it. (Note that the Module Name and command name are same here)

***///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////***

**Update:**
Tried this too i.e. loading the module explicitly from the path ->> with no luck -

```
    var path = ((PSModuleInfo) (((PSObject) (listBox1.SelectedItem)).ImmediateBaseObject)).Path;
    path=path.Replace("system32", "SysWOW64");

    _ps.AddCommand("Import-Module");
    _ps.AddParameter(path);
    _ps.Invoke();
```

**Exception after Update:** [Although Module is present, works perfectly fine in ISE x86 shell]

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MyModules\MyModule1\MyModule1.psm1'.

***///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally :-

Instead of doing this -

```
_ps.AddCommand(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()).Invoke();
```

**Do this -**

```
_ps.AddScript(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()).Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `listBox1.SelectedItem` contain?

If it is just the name `MyModule1` is that found with `$env:PSModulePath`?

I suspect it is not in the module search path, but loaded with a relative path within the module `MyModules`. Therefore you need to pass `Import-Module` an complete path (or, if you can control the current directeory, a relative path) to the module's main file (`.psd1`, `.psm1` or `.dll` as applicable).

Comment: I tried this too but no luck - Have updated the question with this.